# Elastic search on Windows - Error - Native memory allocation (mmap) failed

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

We are running Elastic Search 7.13.2 on a windows server. This was running but suddenly the the ES.bat file is returning an error as below. I have verified that there is no Memory overload in the server. The system has 16 GB RAM, which is 50 percent or less occupied. The free Disk space was > 25GB. Any idea why this error comes up?

I tried to reduce the Heap memory to 4 GB, i created a file named jvm.options inside the jvm.options.d folder and added the below lines, but this doesnt seem to take effect. Any clue on whats going on?

jvm.options file content as below

```
-Xmx4g
-Xms4g
```

Comment: is ES running inside a docker container on the windows server?

Comment: runs on a windows server